# SET every database on a SQL Server instance to "Simple Recovery"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to loop through every database on the instance, check the recovery model, and if it is `Full`, I'd like to change it to `Simple`.

What am I doing wrong here :

```
USE MASTER

DECLARE @isql varchar(2000),
DECLARE @dbname varchar(64)

DECLARE c1 cursor FOR 
    SELECT name 
    FROM master..sysdatabases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT c1 into @dbname

WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
BEGIN
    SELECT @isql = 'ALTER DATABASE @dbname SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    SELECT @isql = 'ALTER DATABASE @dbname SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    SELECT @isql = 'USE @dbname checkpoint'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
> Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'

Comment: Did you encounter any error with your query ?

Comment: It seems to change the recovery model w/o checking whether is already in Simple.

Comment: i don't see you any section of code that does that in your query. Check `sys.databases.dbo.recovery_model`

Comment: Noted that you are still using `sysdatabases`. Do change to `sys.databases`. `sysdatabases` will be removed in future version of `SQL Server` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdatabases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel. Could you please help me add that piece?. I need to check whether the db is already in simple, and skip it. Just change the ones (if any) in Full rec mode.

Comment: `WHERE recovery_model <> 3`

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.

Comment: `OPEN c1 FETCH ~NEXT~ c1 into @dbname`    Remove the `NEXT` here

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your query, you forgot to add `FROM` here : `FETCH NEXT c1 into @dbname`

It should've been `FETCH NEXT FROM c1 into @dbname`

See below code fixed:

```
USE MASTER

DECLARE @isql varchar(2000)
DECLARE @dbname varchar(64)

DECLARE c1 cursor FOR 
    SELECT quotename(name) 
    FROM master..sysdatabases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 into @dbname

WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
BEGIN
    SELECT @isql = 'ALTER DATABASE @dbname SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    SELECT @isql = 'ALTER DATABASE @dbname SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    SELECT @isql = 'USE @dbname checkpoint'
    SELECT @isql = REPLACE (@isql, '@dbname', @dbname)

    PRINT @isql

    EXEC (@isql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```